# Ошибка в jquery коде

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не понимаю, в чем проблема в коде jquery. Мне не надо ничего передавать. Пароли у меня уже получены ранее, а сейчас пользователь вводит пароль (мне нужно их сверить). Но у меня возникают ошибки. Я ошибся в синтаксисе? По скобкам вроде все сходится.

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form');
    form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Добавили, чтобы страница не перезагружалась
        var result = JSON.parse(response);
        $('.pas').attr('style', '');
        var password_1 = result[0].password;
        var password_2 = result[1].password;
       
        var cur_pas1 = $('.cur_pas2').val();
        var cur_pas2 = $('.cur_pas2').val();
        
        if(password_1 == cur_pas1) && (password_2 == cur_pas2)
        {
          $(".player").html('IT IS WORKING!');
         
        }
      },
        });
```

Comment: Не нужно сверять пароли на стороне клиента, пусть это делает серверная часть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, скобки не заметил. Там еще `json.Parse()` лишний был

Итоговая форма без отправки куда-либо. Просто локальная проверка переменных, полученными с этой страницы:

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form-pas');
    form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Добавили, чтобы страница не перезагружалась
        var cur_pas1 = $('.cur_pas1').val();
        var cur_pas2 = $('.cur_pas2').val();
        if((password_1 == cur_pas1) && (password_2 == cur_pas2)) //ВОТ ТУТ СКОБОЧКИ
        {
          $(".player").html('IT IS WORKING!');
         
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа dmitriy_vlz.

Answer (score 1):

А если вот так?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form');
    form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Добавили, чтобы страница не перезагружалась
        var result = JSON.parse(response);
        $('.pas').attr('style', '');
        var password_1 = result[0].password;
        var password_2 = result[1].password;
       
        var cur_pas1 = $('.cur_pas2').val();
        var cur_pas2 = $('.cur_pas2').val();
        
        if((password_1 == cur_pas1) && (password_2 == cur_pas2)) //ВОТ ТУТ СКОБОЧКИ
        {
          $(".player").html('IT IS WORKING!');
         
        }
      },
        });
```

Comment: Нет, точно также из-за какой-то ошибки перезагружается страница. Онлайн валидаторы говорят

Строка Столбец Ошибки  
19 9 Unexpected '}'.    
19 9 Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'.  
1 30 Unmatched '{'.  
19 11 Unrecoverable syntax error. (100% scanned).
@dmitriy_vlz

Comment: Глянь еще свой form.submit(function(event).
Он у тебя закрывается через },
А должен по идеи });